# How to sync local database with cloud database?

Tags: firebase

Can i with Firebase Cloud Messaging send a notification to the client everytime the cloud storage changes, which prompts the client to read from the cloud to update local database?

Is there an other more effective way to ensure the two are always synced?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible via Cloud Storage Triggers.  The [full documentation is here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage), but the general idea is:

- Trigger function runs on Google's servers whenever Cloud Storage files are updated
- Your trigger function sends a push notification via Firebase Cloud Messaging
- Client code acts upon receiving this notification

The documentation contains examples of how to write and deploy a trigger function in multiple languages.  Most likely, you will want your function to trigger on `google.storage.object.finalize` events:

```
Trigger type value: google.storage.object.finalize

This event is sent when a new object is created (or an existing object 
is overwritten, and a new generation of that object is created) in the 
bucket.
```